# Fastest way to find if a point is closer to other points by a certain threshold

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of points in 3 dimensions (x, y and z) and I want to reduce the size of the size of the list. So my idea is to iterate through all points and only add the most important ones, which means that if a new point is too close to any existing one, the new one is discarded. What is the fastest way to do that, instead of just iterate through the whole list when evaluating a new point?

Comment: You can use a k-d tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree